# Replacing an string in a dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a (7,11000) dataframe. in some of these 7 columns, there are strings.
In Coulmn 2 and row 1000, there is a string 'London'. I want to change it to 'Paris'.
how can I do this? I searched all over the web but I couldnt find a way. I used theses commands but none of them works:

```
df['column2'].replace('London','Paris')
df['column2'].str.replace('London','Paris')
re.sub('London','Paris',df['column2'])
```

I usually receive this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Please add the outputs of df.info() to this question.  Secondly, when describing the size of a dataframe, generally the pattern is (rows, columns).  So, your dataframe I think is (11000, 7).  `df['column2'] = df['column2'].replace(to_replace='London', value='Paris')` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace a single row (you mention row 1000), you can do it with `.loc`. If you want to replace all occurrences of `'London'`, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['New York', 'London'],})
df.country = df.country.str.replace('London', 'Paris')
```

Alternatively, you could write your own replacement function, and then use `.apply`:

```
def replace_country(string):
    if string == 'London':
        return 'Paris'
    return string

df.country = df.country.apply(replace_country)
```

The second method is a bit overkill, but is a good example that generalizes better for more complex tasks.

Comment: I didnt use RETURN :(((

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing check for non characters with re

```
import re
for r, map in re_map.items():
    df['column2'] = [re.sub(r, map, x) for x in df['column2']]
```

Comment: Avoid for loops on dataframes unless absolutely necessay. These operations are very slow. Use the inbuilt functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

These are all great answers but many are not vectorized, operating on every item in the series once rather than working on the entire series.

A very reliable filter + replace strategy is to create a mask or subset True/False series and then use loc with that series to replace:

```
mask = df.country == 'London' 
df.loc[mask, 'country'] = 'Paris'

# On 10m records:
  # this method < 1 second 
  # @Charles method 1 < 10 seconds
  # @Charles method 2 < 3.5 seconds
  # @jose method didn't bother because it would be 30 seconds or more
```